# How to handle Two-dimensional Array convert into One-dimensional Array in JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got the Array like the below:

```
[
  {
    companyId: 'TW0826',
    modules: [
      {
        name: 'Module A',
        condition: true,
      },
      {
        name: 'Module B',
        condition: false,
      },
      {
        name: 'Module C',
        condition: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    companyId: 'TXT777',
    modules: [
      {
        name: 'Module B',
        condition: true,
      },
      {
        name: 'Module C',
        condition: false,
      },
      {
        name: 'Module D',
        condition: false,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

But I want to make it like:

```
[
  {companyId:'TW0826', name:'Module A', condition:ture},
  {companyId:'TW0826',name:'Module B', condition:false},
  {companyId:'TXT777',name:'Module B',condition:ture},
  {companyId:'TXT777',name:'Module C',condition:false}....
]
```

So what I can do to reach the above result. Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you want the companyId to be repeated many times for each module? Or just one companyId with one name? Please add a filled-out example output

Comment: Yes, You are right, I wanna have repeated the companyId in its modules:  The result should be:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with an inner [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to convert your nested module arrays into individual objects like so:

```js
const data = [{companyId: 'TW0826', modules: [ { name: 'Module A', condition: true, }, { name: 'Module B', condition: false, }, { name: 'Module C', condition: true, }, ], }, { companyId: 'TXT777', modules: [ { name: 'Module B', condition: true, }, { name: 'Module C', condition: false, }, { name: 'Module D', condition: false, }, ], }, ];

const res = data.flatMap(
  ({companyId, modules}) => 
    modules.map(({name, condition}) => ({companyId, name, condition}))
);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important;} /* ignore */
```

`.flatMap()` does have limited browser support, so you can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) if you need something more browser compatible:

```js
const data = [{companyId: 'TW0826', modules: [ { name: 'Module A', condition: true, }, { name: 'Module B', condition: false, }, { name: 'Module C', condition: true, }, ], }, { companyId: 'TXT777', modules: [ { name: 'Module B', condition: true, }, { name: 'Module C', condition: false, }, { name: 'Module D', condition: false, }, ], }, ];

const res = data.reduce(
  (acc, {companyId, modules}) => 
    [...acc, ...modules.map(({name, condition}) => ({companyId, name, condition}))], []
);

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important;} /* ignore */
```